# Android Javascript injection error Refused to execute inline script

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, javascript-injection

I am facing the following problem:

Whenever I try to inject JS (to an external site) from an assets file I get the following error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https: 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

My code is

```
private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
    //inject function
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        // String-ify the script byte-array using BASE64 encoding !!!
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        String loadFileJS = "" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                "script.async = true;"+
                // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +

                "parent.appendChild(script);" ;


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript(loadFileJS, null);
        } else {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    loadFileJS +
                    "})()");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And this is how I call the inject function

```
injectScriptFile(webview, "Jquery/jquery.min.js");
injectScriptFile(webview, "scripts/functionalityJS.js");
```

**This code is functional with certain websites (eg Facebook) while in others (eg. Dropbox) I get the error-message mentioned above. The error though, is in specific versions of android (eg 5.1) while in other versions (eg 4.2.2) it is working perfectly.**

Any help would be a life-savior :)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?